# Get attribute value of the next or previous row on jquery-ui.sortable on stop() event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a gridview and I've implemented jquery.ui.sortable on it.

I've successfully assigned values for a custom attribute "printorder" which is used for its order in the list. What I need to know is how to get the previous or next attribute value for print order after I drop the sortable item. Here's what I've done so far but it doesnt work as it should:

```
$(function () {
    $("#ListItems tbody").sortable({
        start: function (event, ui) {
            originalIndex = $("#ListItems tr.ListItem").index(ui.item);
            originalPrintOrder = $(ui.item).attr('printorder');
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            endIndex = $("#gvInvItems tr.ListItem").index(ui.item);
            if (endIndex < originalIndex) {
                newPrintOrder = $(ui.item).prev().attr('printorder') + 1;
            }
            if (endIndex > originalIndex) {
                newPrintOrder = $(ui.item).next(1).attr('printorder') - 1;
            }
            if (originalIndex == endIndex) {
                return;
            }
            ChangeOrder(originalPrintOrder, newPrintOrder, $(ui.item).attr('ItemGUID'));
        },
        handle: ".dragHandle"
    });
    $("#ListItems tbody").sortable({
        items: 'tr.RowStyle, tr.AltRowStyle'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my code works well as. The problem was that I was adding strings so if I moved 5 rows 5 the code should add 1 to the previous row so it should be 4 + 1 = 5. But since I did not convert it to int (Number()) it only appended each other as strings so 4 + 1 = 41.

Noob mistake really. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the [Api-Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/). Use the [update event](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update) and jQuery [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to get the elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/CZtLe/2/

```
$(function () {

    $('ul').sortable({
        update: function (event, ui) {
            var prevElement = ui.item.prev();
            var nextElement = ui.item.next();
            $('span#prev').html(prevElement.html());
            $('span#next').html(nextElement.html());
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: have to say, theres no update for the specific element if theres no prev (moving to first position) or next (moving to last position) but i guess this is no problem

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will totally keep that noted.